# Flutter adding to state using Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-freezed

After search and learn more about how can i add or update some field of data structure, we have below implementation

here we want to have a simple `order` structure with data which user can add service to order or update selected service count, for example in first time user doesn't selected any service then we have `OrderStructure:[]` which we initial that in `constructor`:

```dart
OrderNotifier() : super(_initial);
static OrderStructure _initial = OrderStructure('', []);
```

when user selected any service we pass three argument to `increment` method:

```dart
void increment({required int productId, required int serviceId, required int serviceCost})
```

if service doesn't exist it should be add which that belongs to product. each service belongs to product and we store that with productId
in `increment` method we pass `productId`, `serviceId` and `serviceCost`, which can search into class data structure as OrderStructure.

if productId exist then we try to search serviceId, if serviceId exists. `productId = true && serviceId = true` then we should increment `count` value,
if it doesn't exist it should be save as new item
notice we should't have multiple the same `productId` or `serviceId` into `OrderStructure`.

each of them must be unique. each product can be have multiple service such as `List`, `OrderStructure` shouldn't have multiple `productId`

for example `OrderStructure` data structure can be:

```php
OrderStructure:
   title : 'sample',
   products:[
       productId: 1
       services : [
         [serviceId:1, count:1, cost: 100],
         [serviceId:2, count:9, cost: 500],
         [serviceId:3, count:5, cost: 2000],
       ],
       productId: 2
       services : [
         [serviceId:3, count:10, cost: 100],
         [serviceId:5, count:6, cost: 500]
       ],
       productId: 3
       services : [
         [serviceId:3, count:10, cost: 100],
         [serviceId:5, count:6, cost: 500],
         [serviceId:6, count:6, cost: 500],
         [serviceId:7, count:6, cost: 500],
         [serviceId:8, count:6, cost: 500],
       ],
   ]
```

when user selected `seriveId` id `1` and `productId` id is `1`, we search in this collection with `productId` and then `serviceId`, if its exists then `count` should be increment, otherwise it should be added into `OrderStructure` collection as a new one

for example:

```php
OrderStructure:
   title : 'sample',
   products:[
       productId: 1
       services : [
         [serviceId:1, count:2, cost: 100],
         ...
```

we have this code, but it doesn't correct:

```dart
void increment({required int productId, required int serviceId, required int serviceCost}) {
  final newState = OrderStructure(state.title, [
    ...state.products,
    for (final product in state.products)
      if (product.id == productId)
        for (final service in product.services)
          if (service.id == serviceId)
            SelectedProducts(productId,
                [...product.services, SelectedProductServices(service.id, service.count + 1, service.cost)])
  ]);
  // ignore: iterable_contains_unrelated_type
  if (!newState.products.contains(productId) ||
      // ignore: iterable_contains_unrelated_type
      !newState.products.firstWhere((p) => p.id == productId).services.contains(serviceId)) {
    newState.products.add(
        SelectedProducts(serviceId, <SelectedProductServices>[SelectedProductServices(serviceId, 1, serviceCost)]));
  }
  state = newState;
}
```

FULL CODE:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,ScopedReader watch) {
    final _orderProvider = watch(orderStateNotifierProvider.notifier);
    final _product = SelectedProducts(1, []);
    final _service = SelectedProductServices(1, 1, 111);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('add new service'),
              onPressed: ()=>context.read(orderStateNotifierProvider.notifier)
                  .increment(productId:1, serviceId:1, serviceCost:100),
            ),

            // here we want to add new service to product, the same as above code, if productId doesn't exists
            // into `OrderStructure` it should be save with
            TextButton(
              child: Text('append service to product`s services'),
              onPressed: ()=>context.read(orderStateNotifierProvider.notifier)
                  .increment(productId:1, serviceId:2, serviceCost:500),
            ),

            Text('product`s service count: ${_orderProvider.state.products[0].services.length}')
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}


//------------------------


final orderStateNotifierProvider = StateNotifierProvider<OrderNotifier, OrderStructure>((ref) => OrderNotifier());

class OrderNotifier extends StateNotifier<OrderStructure> {
  OrderNotifier() : super(_initial);
  static OrderStructure _initial = OrderStructure('', []);

  void resetOrder() {
    _initial = const OrderStructure('', []);
  }

  void updateAddress({
    required String title,
  }) {
    state = OrderStructure(title,state.products);
  }


  void increment({required int productId, required int serviceId, required int serviceCost}) {
    final newState = OrderStructure(state.title, [
      ...state.products,
      for (final product in state.products)
        if (product.id == productId)
          for (final service in product.services)
            if (service.id == serviceId)
              SelectedProducts(productId,
                  [...product.services, SelectedProductServices(service.id, service.count + 1, service.cost)])
    ]);
    // ignore: iterable_contains_unrelated_type
    if (!newState.products.contains(productId) ||
        // ignore: iterable_contains_unrelated_type
        !newState.products.firstWhere((p) => p.id == productId).services.contains(serviceId)) {
      newState.products.add(
          SelectedProducts(serviceId, <SelectedProductServices>[SelectedProductServices(serviceId, 1, serviceCost)]));
    }
    state = newState;
  }
}

class OrderStructure {
  final String title;
  final List<SelectedProducts> products;

  const OrderStructure(this.title, this.products);
}

class SelectedProducts {
  final int id;
  final List<SelectedProductServices> services;

  SelectedProducts(this.id, this.services);
}

class SelectedProductServices {
  final int id;
  final int count;
  final int cost;

  const SelectedProductServices(this.id, this.count, this.cost);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed issues, `increment` method should be:

```dart
void increment(int productId, int serviceId, int serviceCost) {
  final newState = OrderStructure(state.title, state.address, state.lat, state.lang, state.pelak, state.vahed, []);
  for (final product in state.products) {
    if (product.id == productId) {
      if (product.services.any((s) => s.id == serviceId)) {
        final service = product.services.firstWhere((s) => s.id == serviceId);
        newState.products.add(SelectedProducts(productId, [
          ...product.services.where((s) => s.id != serviceId),
          SelectedProductServices(service.id, service.count + 1, service.cost)
        ]));
      } else {
        newState.products.add(
            SelectedProducts(productId, [...product.services, SelectedProductServices(serviceId, 1, serviceCost)]));
      }
    } else {
      newState.products.add(product);
    }
  }
  if (!newState.products.any((p) => p.id == productId) ||
      !newState.products.firstWhere((p) => p.id == productId).services.any((s) => s.id == serviceId)) {
    // Add new
    newState.products.add(SelectedProducts(productId, [SelectedProductServices(serviceId, 1, serviceCost)]));
  }
  state = newState;
}
```

thanks to [TimWhiting](https://github.com/TimWhiting)

Answer (score 1):

##### You need to do something like this.

```dart
void increment(int productId, int serviceId, int serviceCost) {
  // copy the old state
  final newState = OrderStructure(state.title, [...state.products]);
  bool updated = false;
  /// We directly iterate on the newState.
  for(final product in newState.products){
      if( product.id != productId ) {
          continue; // jump to next the product because the current product do not match.
       } 
      updated = true; // We are sure that the product already exist.
      // We search the first index of service that has `id` equal to `serviceId`.
      final serviceIndex = product.services.indexWhere( (s) => s.id == serviceId );
      if( serviceIndex >= 0 ) {
         product.services[serviceIndex].count ++;
         break;
      }
      final newService = SelectedProductServices(serviceId, 1, serviceCost);
      product.services.add(newService);
      break;
  }
  // Now we only check if we have not made an update.
  if(!update) {
    final newService = SelectedProductServices(serviceId, 1, serviceCost);
    final newProduct =  SelectedProduct(productId, [newService]);
    newState.products.add(newProduct); 
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, i think you answered in my another issues, thanks. but i have a issue with your code. i invited you in chat to resolve this problem. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128804/riverpod

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to update the whole `OrderStructure`, only the reference to the inner list that contains the service to update:

```dart
void increment({required int productId, required int serviceId, required int serviceCost}) {
  final OrderStructure order = state;

  final int productIndex = order.products.indexWhere((product) => product.id == productId);

  final SelectedProducts product;
  // If the product has not been found, add it to the products
  if (productIndex == -1) {
    product = SelectedProducts(productId, []);
    order.products.add(product);

  // Otherwise, just get it
  } else {
    product = order.products[productIndex];
  }

  final int serviceIndex = product.services.indexWhere((service) => service.id == serviceId && service.cost == serviceCost);
  
  // If the service has not been found, add it to the services
  if (serviceIndex == -1) {
    product.services.add(SelectedProductServices(serviceId, 1, serviceCost));
  
  // Otherwise, just update its counter
  } else {
    final SelectedProductServices service = product.services[serviceIndex];
    product.services[serviceIndex] = SelectedProductServices(service.id, service.count + 1, service.cost);
  }

  // Set the state to the updated order structure
  state = order;
}
```

For the decrement part, just do `service.count - 1` on the last line.

Comment: did you test by yourself? i'm not sure because i get error `Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list`

Comment: Try removing the `const` inside `resetOrder`.

Comment: i dont' use this function now